# How to define and link full path to css located at a random folder on header.php

Tags: theme-development, css

I want to link css and .js script on my header.php file, problem is I am not sure what should be the starting point of the directory
Below is the directory where my file is located:

Example path: link href="path/to/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">

Path in my server:
/public_html/wp-content/themes/totalduplicate/lightbox2-master/lightbox2-master/src/css

THank you

Comment: read the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/), google examples.

Comment: To properly add scripts and styles to a WordPress theme you need to enqueue the files from your functions file. See the documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) and [`wp_enque_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/), they'll handle the assembly and placement of the script/style tag, and the dependancy order - inside of your header (via [`wp_head()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/)) or footer if you like to load your assets at the bottom of your page.

So, for your example, something like

```
add_action( "wp_enqueue_scripts", function(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 
        'mythemelightbox', 
        get_template_directory_uri().'/lightbox2-master/lightbox2-master/src/css/lightbox.css', 
        [], 
        false
    );
});
```

note that [`get_template_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) is what builds your current domain with the path to the current theme.

Comment: If this is the function WHat should be the full path?

function wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src = '', $deps = array(), $ver = false, $in_footer = false ) {
    $wp_scripts = wp_scripts();
 
    _wp_scripts_maybe_doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__ );
 
 
    if ( $src || $in_footer ) {
        $_handle = explode( '?', $handle );
 
        if ( $src ) {
            $wp_scripts->add( $_handle[0], $src, $deps, $ver );
        }
 
        if ( $in_footer ) {
            $wp_scripts->add_data( $_handle[0], 'group', 1 );
        }
    }
 
    $wp_scripts->enqueue( $handle );
}

Comment: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/